# Converting large string of dictionaries to dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a big dataframe consisting of 144005 rows. One of the columns of the dataframe is a string of dictionaries like

```
'{"Step ID":"78495","Choice Number":"0","Campaign Run ID":"23199"},
    {"Step ID":"78495","Choice Number":"0","Campaign Run ID":"23199"},
    {"Step ID":"78495","Choice Number":"0","Campaign Run ID":"23199"}'
```

I want to convert this string to seperate dictionaries. I have been using `json.loads()` for this purpose, however, I have had to iterate over this string of dictionary one at a time, convert it to a dictionary using `json.loads()`, then convert this to a new dataframe and keep appending to this dataframe while I iterate over the entire original dataframe.

I wanted to know whether there was a more efficient way to do this as it takes a long time to iterate over an entire dataframe of 144005 rows.

Here is a snippet of what I have been doing:

```
d1 = df1['attributes'].values
d2 = df1['ID'].values
for i,j in zip(d1,d2):
    data = json.loads(i)
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [j])
    temp['ID'] = j
    df2 = df2.append(temp, sort=False)
```

My 'attributes' column consist of a string of dictionary as a row, and the 'Id' column contains it's corresponding Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it myself.

I used `map` along with `lambda` functions to efficiently apply `json.loads()` on each row, then I converted this data to a dataframe and stored the output.

Here it is.

```
l1 = df1['attributes'].values
data = map(lambda x: json.loads(x), l1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the type of your column by using `type()`

If the type is `Series`:

```
data['your column name'].apply(pd.Series)
```

then you will see all keys as separate column in a dataframe with their key values.

Comment: Don't post code in images. Please write it in blocks. Check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Doesn't work, just returns the same thing. the columns is still a string of dictionaries. I think in your image, the 'stationBeanList' column is a dictionary and not a string of dictionary.